# Should a forbidden page always respond with a 403 code?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

I have a ColdFusion website that programmatically handles "forbidden"/"unauthorized" requests in `onrequeststart()` in `Application.cfc` based on the logged in user's attributes. For example (FYI: `SESSION.User` is initialized in `onSessionStart()`:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="Boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="targetPage" type="string" required="true">

    <cfparam name="REQUEST.MinSecurityLevel" default="0" />
    <cfparam name="REQUEST.IsLoginRequired" default="false" />

    <cfif REQUEST.IsLoginRequired AND NOT SESSION.User.isLoggedIn()>
        <cfscript>
            SESSION.LoginMessage =
                "Your session has timed out. Please log in again.";
            SESSION.LastPageVisited =
                getPageContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();

            if (Len(Trim(getPageContext().getRequest().getQueryString())))
                SESSION.LastPageVisited =
                        SESSION.LastPageVisited
                    &   "?"
                    &   getPageContext().getRequest().getQueryString();
        </cfscript>

        <cflocation url="/user/login/" addtoken="false" />
    <cfelseif SESSION.User.getSecurityLevel() LT REQUEST.MinSecurityLevel>
        <cfheader statuscode="403" statustext="Forbidden" />
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

In IIS (version 7), I have an error page setting with Type "Execute URL" and my custom 403 page path.

I am able to trigger this, and it properly displays my custom 403 page, but it returns a HTTP Response Code 200.

Shouldn't this return a 403?

Comment: I am confused on what you are asking. The title suggests that you are asking if a 403 code should be returned for a particular situation but your question seems to point out an issue where you are attempting to send back a 403 code but are actually getting a 200 code returned. Can you clarify? If it is the latter, I have the same issue with 404 codes that I handle with ColdFusion.

Comment: Would you want to do a cfabort right after the cfheader to stop all future processing?  I think that would guarantee that you get the 403 returned.

Comment: @RandyJohnson Adding a CFABORT has the same result. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Miguel-F I guess I am asking both questions - should it always return 403 (best practice) and why isn't my app returning a 403? I have a solution in place for 404s in ColdFusion/IIS: 1. Don't use onMissingTemplate(). 2. Setup IIS to "always check that file exists". 3. Setup custom error page for 404 as Execute URL to your custom 404 path (mine is "/missing-template/index.cfm", then at the top of that template file add: <cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found" />. This works great for me to catch all 404s - CF and otherewise.

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears that REQUEST.MinSecurityLevel will always be 0.  Will SESSION.User.getSecurityLevel() ever return a negative number?

Comment: @DanBracuk No, it will not always be Zero. There is a lot more code that is not included here - retrieving the security level from the database and setting it as a User attribute, as well as the places where REQUEST.MinSecurityLevel is set in many different Application.cfc below the root.

Comment: @EricBelair on your 404 responses are you displaying a custom page using ColdFusion or just sending back the 404 error header? My situation is that when I send back a 404 then IIS displays it's own 404 error instead of my custom ColdFusion page. Even though I have the IIS 404 handler set to execute URL of my ColdFusion page. I'm sure it is specific to my configuration (which is not standard).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though I found a solution in my response to @Miguel-F above. I simply mimicked part of what I'm doing to handle 404 errors:

**/missing-template/index.cfm:**

```
<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found" />
```

**/not-authorized/index.cfm:**

```
<cfheader statuscode="403" statustext="Forbidden" />
```

I thought that adding a 403 header to the 403 handler page would result in an endless loop, but it works fine.

I also added  in onRequestStart() since there's no need for further processing once the 403 is triggered:

```
<cfelseif SESSION.User.getSecurityLevel() LT REQUEST.MinSecurityLevel>
    <cfheader statuscode="403" statustext="Forbidden" />

    <cfreturn false />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Great glad you got it working! To answer your other question, for pages where user authentication is required I typically return a 401 Unauthorized. Read these descriptions from w3.org - **401** _The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field._ **403** _The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated._